# connect input and output tensors of two different graphs tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have **2 *ProtoBuf*** Files, I currently load and forward pass each of them separately, by calling-

```
out1=session.run(graph1out, feed_dict={graph1inp:inp1})
```

followed by

```
final=session.run(graph2out, feed_dict={graph2inp:out1})
```

where ***graph1inp*** and ***graph1out*** are input node and output node of **graph 1** and similar terminology for **graph 2**

Now, I want to connect ***graph1out*** with ***graph2inp*** such that I only have to run ***graph2out*** while feeding ***graph1inp*** with ***inp1***. In other words connecting the input and output tensors of the 2 involved graphs in such a way that one run is sufficient to run inference on both trained *ProtoBuf* files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that your Protobuf files contain serialized [`tf.GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f8d1f5b5aa07d395bcba105f1f3d5d76f53d4546/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto) protos, you can use the `input_map` argument of [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) to connect the two graphs:

```
# Import graph1.
graph1_def = ...  # tf.GraphDef object
out1_name = "..."  # name of the graph1out tensor in graph1_def.
graph1out, = tf.import_graph_def(graph1_def, return_elements=[out_name])

# Import graph2 and connect it to graph1.
graph2_def = ...  # tf.GraphDef object
inp2_name = "..."  # name of the graph2inp tensor in graph2_def.
out2_name = "..."  # name of the graph2out tensor in graph2_def.
graph2out, = tf.import_graph_def(graph2_def, input_map={inp2_name: graph1out},
                                 return_elements=[out2_name])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks to help me!

Comment: I am getting "'outputs' in input_map does not exist in graph (input_map entry: decoder_inputs:0->outputs:0)" - not quite sure why. Obviously, "outputs" does not exist in the second graph. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer does connect two graphs, however it does not restore the collections, global and trainable variables. After an exhaustive search I came to a better solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import meta_graph

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph1:
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 20), name='input')
    output = tf.identity(input, name='output')

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph2:
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 20), name='input')
    output = tf.identity(input, name='output')

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 20), name='input')
```

We use `tf.train.export_meta_graph` that exports also [CollectionDef](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph) and `meta_graph.import_scoped_meta_graph` to import it. Here is where the connection happens, specifically in `input_map` parameter.

```
meta_graph1 = tf.train.export_meta_graph(graph=graph1)
meta_graph.import_scoped_meta_graph(meta_graph1, input_map={'input': x}, import_scope='graph1')
out1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('graph1/output:0')

meta_graph2 = tf.train.export_meta_graph(graph=graph2)
meta_graph.import_scoped_meta_graph(meta_graph2, input_map={'input': out1}, import_scope='graph2')
```

Now graph is connected as well as global variables are being re-mapped.

```
print(tf.global_variables())
```

You can also import meta graphs directly from a file.