# Connecting nodes of different GraphDef's

Tags: c++, tensorflow

From Python, I have a frozen `graph.pb` that I'm currently using in a C++ environment. Now the data for the input tensor are currently preprocessed on the CPU, but I would like to do this step in another GraphDef to run it on the GPU, but I can't seem to find a way to connect nodes between two `GraphDef`'s.

Lets assume my frozen graph have an input/placeholder named `mid` that I'd like to connect with the preprocessing steps below

```
tf::GraphDef create_graph_extension() {
    tf::Scope root = tf::Scope::NewRootScope();

    auto a = tf::ops::Const(root.WithOpName("in"), {(float) 23.0, (float) 31.0});
    auto b = tf::ops::Identity(root.WithOpName("mid"), a);

    tf::GraphDef graph;
    TF_CHECK_OK(root.ToGraphDef(&graph));
    return graph;
}
```

I usually use `session->Extend()` to run multiple graphs in the same session, but always making sure their node names are unique. With non-unique node names, that I hoped to connect, I get an error

```
Failed to install graph:
Invalid argument: GraphDef argument to Extend includes node 'mid', which 
was created by a previous call to Create or Extend in this session.
```

P.s. It seems like it is possible in python at least ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858785/connect-input-and-output-tensors-of-two-different-graphs-tensorflow))

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking for using the same idea that was suggested for Python - import one GraphDef into another and remap inputs.

In case you do use the C API (which has [stability guarantees](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat)), you'd want to look at:

- [`TF_GraphImportGraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L912) (which is parallel to the `tf.import_graph_def` call in Python), and
- [`TF_ImportGraphDefOptionsAddInputMapping`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L872) which serves the same purpose as the `input_map` argument in Python.

These are implemented on top of the C++ [`ImportGraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.h#L118) function, which you might be able to use directly instead (though that doesn't seem to yet be part of the exported C++ API)

Hope that helps.