# Using custom error function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a trained convolutional neural network **A** that outputs the propability that a given picture contains a square or a circle.

Another Network **B** takes images of random noise. My idea is to have a bunch of convolutional layers so that the output is a newly generated square.
As an error function I would like to feed the generated image into **A** and learn filters of **B** from the softmax tensor of **A**. To my understanding this is sort of a generative adversarial network, except for that **A** does not learn. While trying to implement this I have encountered two problems.

1. I have imported the Layers of **A** that I want to use in **B** as followed:

   ```
   with gfile.FastGFile("shape-classifier.pb", 'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
       image_input_layer, extern_softmax_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(
           graph_def, name="", return_elements=["image_input", "Softmax"])
   ```

   I would like to avoid using two sess.run() three times. (Generating the random image, getting the softmax values from **A**, adjusting weights of **B**).
   Is there a way to directly connect the tensors so that I only have one graph?

   Calling:

   ```
   logits = extern_softmax_tensor(my_generated_image_tensor)
   ```

   throws:

   ```
   TypeError: 'Operation' object is not callable
   ```

   The "Graph-Connected" and the "Feed-Connected" approach confuse me a bit.
2. ```
   logits = extern_softmax_tensor(my_generated_image_tensor) # however you would call it
   cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_input,
                                                           logits=logits)
   cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy_tensor)
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
   learning_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy_mean)
   ```

   With that Logic the error will be first passed back through **A**.
   Is there a way to use the softmax calculated by **A** to directly adjust Layers of **B**?

Leaving aside if my idea actually works, is it actually possible to build it in tensorflow? I hope I could make my problems clear.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to [connect two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858785/connect-input-and-output-tensors-of-two-different-graphs-tensorflow) like that.

```
# Generator networ
my_generated_image_tensor = ...
# Read classifier
with gfile.FastGFile("shape-classifier.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    # Map generator output to classifier input
    extern_softmax_tensor, = tf.import_graph_def(
        graph_def, name="", input_map={"image_input": my_generated_image_tensor},
        return_elements=["Softmax:0"])
# Define loss and training step
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=label_input, logits=extern_softmax_tensor)
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy_tensor)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
learning_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy_mean)
```

As side notes: 1) [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) expects logits as input, that is, the values *before* being passed through the softmax function, so if the `Softmax` tensor in the loaded model is the output of a softmax operation you should probably change it to use the input logits instead. 2) Note that [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is now deprecated anyway, see [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2).

Comment: Note that I had to append the `:0` to the **return_elements**, so that the function returns a tensor. Now the code is running. Thanks!

Comment: @fst Thanks for noting that, fixed.